# ¿Como ajustar un div al tamaño de su contenido con flexbox?

Tags: css3, vue.js, vue3

Pongo en contexto, me encuentro haciendo una aplicación en vuejs sobre pokemons donde la idea es mostrar cierta cantidad de pokemons con todos, sus datos pero me encuentro con un problema a nivel de css, me gustaría que todos los pokemons estuviesen centrados en mi app para esto decidí utilizar flexbox en todo,  practicamente todos mis componentes tienen flex y eso me ha ayudado muchísimo a tener mi página responsiva, el problema que presento ahora es que trato de que mis cards de pokemons estén centrados pero se muestra como si estuviesen en fila.

[image: pokedex app1]

Como pueden ver en la imagen hay un espacio restante, mi itención es mantener mis pokemon cards como se ven actualmente pero que estén mas centrado, yo para tratar de solucionar esto intenté lo siguiente:

```
 <template>
   <div class="pokedex-page">
      <div class="container">
        <PokemonCard v-for="{id, name} in pokemonsPerPage" :key="id" :id="id" :name="name"/>
     </div>
   </div>
 </template>

<style scoped lang="css">
.pokedex-page{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 8em);
  background-color: #414770;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
</style>
```

Lo que hice fue que a mi div principal de mi componente `pokedex-page` le añadí un `display: flex; justify-content: center;` para que todos los items que esten dentro de él siempre estuviesen centrados en mi app, después para mantener mis pokemons-cards como yo quería (en filas) lo que hice fue añadirlos en un `container` la cual le di las propiedades css que muestra en el codigo anterior, esto lo hice con el motivo de que mi `container`ocupase el ancho de los elementos que contiene porque actualmente mi `container` tiene exactamente el mismo ancho que mi `pokedex-page` y debido a esto no se puede ver visualmente bien que está centrado aunque en teoria lo está haciendo pero por algún motivo `display: inline-flex;` no está funcionando, mi objetivo es que mi `container`tenga el ancho exacto para que el `justify-content: center;` pueda tomar el espacio que resta.

[Aquí un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr.](https://altruistas.org/academia/cursoflexbox/estructura_basica.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar **justify-content: space-between;** va a ayudarte a que todos lo items que tengas se ajusten según el campo del contenedor

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).